# How can I extract a CDATA value from the structure created by XML::Simple?

Tags: xml, perl, cdata

I use a Perl script with the module [XML:Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple) to parse an XML feed:

```
my $xml=XMLin($resp->content);
my $xml2 = $xml->{params}{param}{value}{array}{data}{value}{struct}{member};


print $xml2->{prod_id}{value}{int}; #works fine

print $xml2->{product_text}{value}{string}; #returns a hash reference (hash(0x...)
```

What have I to modify to get the text:

```
<div class="text"> <div class="text_products">sdfsdf</div> </div>
```

instead of a hash reference?

This is the XML data:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <methodResponse>
- <params>
- <param>
- <value>
- <array>
- <data>
- <value>
- <struct>
- <member>
  <name>product_text</name> 
- <value>
  <string><![CDATA[ <div class="text"> <div class="text_products">sdfsdf</div> </div> ]]></string> 
  </value>
  </member>
- <member>
  <name>prod_id</name> 
- <value>
  <int>1290</int> 
  </value>
  </member>
- <member>.......
```

Comment: What is the content of the hash reference? If you use Data::Dumper you should see what keys are available in the hash.

Comment: print Dumper($xml2->{product_text}{value}{string}); produces the following output:

$VAR1 = "<![CDATA[
<div class="text"> <div class="text_products">sdfsdf</div> </div>
]]>";


I use version 2.18 of xml::simple

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work for me. I copied your XML and your perl code and it prints:

```
1290 <div class="text"> <div class="text_products">sdfsdf</div> </div>
```

Using Data::Dumper will show the data structure that exists. For example, when I run your sample code, an extract of the relevant section is:

```
'value' => {
  'string' => ' <div class="text"> <div class="text_products">sdfsdf</div> </div> '
}
```

The only reason I can think that you might be getting something different is if there's another element called product_text at the same level.

**EDIT:** 
If you are sometimes getting empty elements and they are coming out as a hashref, you can set the `SuppressEmpty` option to undef when you call `XMLin`. See the docs for more details ( link : https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#SuppressEmpty-1-undef-in-out---handy )

Comment: I use 

my $xml=XMLin($resp->content);

print Dumper($xml);

to show all the xml data.

How can I show the key value pairs with data dumper?

Comment: Edited to explain a little more about Data::Dumper

Comment: sorry my fault.. there was an error at the xml senders site.

Thank you guys

Comment: mopoke, you were absolutely correct. There was a configuration error of the xml server. element "product_text" has been submitted empty to the script with xml::simple. Another script I have used with Data Dumper received the data because the call was done with a different procedure (xml::rpc)

Comment: Glad to be of help. I've edited the answer to give you hints on XML::Simple options which may let you deal with both cases more elegantly.